# Create an exec on mac to compile

Tags: mac, makefile

I'm trying to create an exec on mac to compile Latex, MakeIndex and BibTex in same time.

Here my make file :

```
latex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode sample.tex
makeindex build/sample.idx
makeindex build/sample.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o build/sample.nls
latex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode sample.tex
bibtex build/sample
latex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode sample.tex
latex -output-directory=build -interaction=nonstopmode sample.tex
```

But when I launch this exec with this in my sample folder, Terminal return me "Command not found".

I think this is a path problem but I'm not really efficient in this domain...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Why don't you use `latexmk`?

Comment: You could also use the `arara` package; see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/arara/doc for information on how to get started with `arara`.

Comment: I use `latexmk`, but I prefer generalize the compilation, for `xelatex` for instance.

This make file run wthout problem on Ubuntu

Comment: If that is indeed a `make` file, can you post the whole thing, and the output of `ls -Al` from its directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you gave your exec file execution rights:

```
chmod a+x yourexecfile.sh
```

If this doesn't help, type in your terminal

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin
```

If this solves the problem, add this at the end of your `.bashrc` file in your home folder. If there is already a similar line like this, just add `:/usr/texbin`to it, e.g.,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Comment: I think the OP's problem isn't that commands such as `latex` and `bibtex` aren't found. I suspect that his/her "exec file" isn't found by the shell.

Comment: He doesn't specify, so we don't know... "Command not found" sounds like a `PATH` problem to me.

Comment: Good point. He/she may also have forgotten to do a `chmod a+x` on the shell script file -- or it may be located in a place not searched by the shell...

Comment: Ah, of course. I'll edit my answer. If he uses a standard setup, which places wouldn't be searched by the shell?